# PostgreSQL implement CONTAINS for array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, postgresql

I need to check whether a string contains(LIKE) one of the substrings from separated by space(" ") delimiter values.

For example, I need to select rows where *c.name* field (with 'TEST-DOWNEY' value for ex.) contains one of the substrings from 'TEST CLIN HOSP' string.

I try to use **LIKE ANY** operator, but it requires '%' char before and after each substring in the array:

```
SELECT c.name FROM contact c
WHERE c.name LIKE ANY (regexp_split_to_array('TEST CLIN HOSP', E' '))
```

But if I run it like this:

```
SELECT c.name FROM contact c
    WHERE c.name LIKE ANY (regexp_split_to_array('%TEST% %CLIN% %HOSP%', E' '))
```

it works.

So how can I dynamically add *'%'* chars to every substring in the array after splitting it to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with contact (name) as (values ('TEST-DOWNEY'))
select c.name
from contact c
where (
    select sum(strpos(c.name, p))
    from regexp_split_to_table('TEST CLIN HOSP', E' ') p(p)
) > 0
;
    name     
-------------
 TEST-DOWNEY
```